# I want to increment a value for each loop. Suppose there are total 8 loop value increment should be in No. column in table 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

Tags: xslt-1.0

```
<tr>
  <center>
    <table class="TableDtl" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;">
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 5%;">
          <b>No.</b>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 7%;">
          <b>Title</b>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 10%">
          <b>First Name</b>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 10%">
          <b>Last Name</b>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 7%">
          <b>Type</b>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 7%">
          <b>Nationality</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="BookingXML/PassengerDetails/Passenger">
        <xsl:variable name="PaxCount" select="position()" />
        <xsl:for-each select="Adults/Adult">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="$PaxCount"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="/BookingXML/PassengerDetails/Passenger/Adults/Adult/Title"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="/BookingXML/PassengerDetails/Passenger/Adults/Adult/FirstName"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="/BookingXML/PassengerDetails/Passenger/Adults/Adult/LastName"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              Adult
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="/BookingXML/HotelInfo/Hotel_Booking_RQ/Master/@NationalityName"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="Childs/Child">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="$PaxCount"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="/BookingXML/PassengerDetails/Passenger/Childs/Child/Title"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="/BookingXML/PassengerDetails/Passenger/Childs/Child/FirstName"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="/BookingXML/PassengerDetails/Passenger/Childs/Child/LastName"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              Child
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="/BookingXML/HotelInfo/Hotel_Booking_RQ/Master/@NationalityName"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="Infants/Infant">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="$PaxCount"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="/BookingXML/PassengerDetails/Passenger/Infants/Infant/Title"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="/BookingXML/PassengerDetails/Passenger/Infants/Infant/FirstName"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="/BookingXML/PassengerDetails/Passenger/Infants/Infant/LastName"/>
            </td>
            <td>
              Infant
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="/BookingXML/HotelInfo/Hotel_Booking_RQ/Master/@NationalityName"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </center>
  <br/>
  <br/>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please show the input XML and the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your existing code, I would guess (!) you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/BookingXML">
    <xsl:variable name="nationality" select="HotelInfo/Hotel_Booking_RQ/Master/@NationalityName" />
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Nationality</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="PassengerDetails/Passenger/*/*"">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
                </td>
                 <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$nationality"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Untested (because no input was provided).

Comment: there are not one foreach loop there are 3 foreach loop and i handal variable increment for every loop.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand what you're saying. I suggest you edit your question as I asked.

Comment: I have 3 foreach loop, one for Adult one for child and one for Infant. Let suppose there are 2 Adult, 2 Child And 2 Infant in xml. so how could we manage a variable which contain 1 for Adult 1, 2 for Adult 2, 3 for child 1 and so on.

Comment: The simplest method is to have a single `xsl:for-each` instruction for all three types - as suggested in my answer. If this does not solve your problem, then edit your question and clarify exactly what you have and what you want to have. I will not ask again.